# Passing JSON through cURL POST PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, laravel-4

I've been trying to pass JSON though my web application using cURL - and I am a little stuck now.

Here is what I've tried :

> **Step 1:**

I tried to **post** JSON using this

```
<?php 

  public function post(){

    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    $json = json_encode($cars);

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api_v2/url?key=***");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $json));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

  }

?>
```

> **Step 2:**

I tried to **receive** JSON back using this

```
public function get(){

        $json = json_decode(Input::get('json'));
        dd($json); // null

    }
```

> **Result:**
>   - I keep getting null when I do `dd($json);`

Can someone please help me point out what did I do wrong ?

---

> **Detail :**

- I use PHP Framework : Laravel 4.0
- I am positive that URL parameter is correct because I can go to it
- I am also sure that the JSON is not broken because after added `print("<h1> JSON </h1><pre>".print_r($json,true)."</pre><br><hr><br>");` I can see my JSON display fine.
- See [Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Screenpresso/proof.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a framework? If so add the tag to the question. If not, what's wrong with $_POST['json'] instead of Input::get('json')?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what's on the server-side?

Comment: @TommyBs : I used PHP Framework : Laravel 4.0

Comment: @EdsonMedina :  Please correct me if I am wrong, I am new to this cURL world. I hope you don't mind helping out by giving me more detail suggestion.

Comment: Several things coul dbe wrong here... The response could be empty (or contain a broken json file), the url could be wrong (or contain the wrong parameters), the end point can be broken... Don't even know where to start. We need more details.

Comment: @EdsonMedina: The URL parameter is correct + the JSON is not broken - and what do you mean by the end point ?

Comment: So, function post() does a POST request to your api and gets the answer in a variable called $response (not used anywhere). Then you have a separate function get() that outputs a GET parameter. How are the two related to each other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70147/discussion-between-kula-and-edson-medina).

Answer (score 0):

As far as your debugging efforts, you should dump the *response* rather than `json_decode`(s) attempt to parse it.

So change this

```
public function get() {
    $json = json_decode(Input::get('json'));
    dd($json); // null
}
```

to this

```
public function get() {
    dd(Input::get('json'));
}
```

That should better help you track down the real problem, which most likely is that the server isn't responding with valid JSON.

Another option is to use [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to see why the response was unparseable.

```
public function get() {
    $json = json_decode(Input::get('json'));

    // If the response was parseable, return it
    if($json !== null)
        return $json;

    // Determine if the response was a valid null or
    // why it was unparseable
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        // The server could respond with a valid null,
        // so go ahead and return it.
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $json;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
            break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: When I do `dd(Input::get('json'));` I got `null` when I go to the URL

Comment: There you go... You're not getting valid JSON back from the service!

Comment: When I tried your other suggestion, I got nothing. It seems that my post function is not passing the **JSON** though **cURL**. Do I need to return anything at the end of my `post()` function ?

Comment: OMG, I see the problem... I'll put a new answer tho, sec.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't returning the results of the cURL call.

```
public function post()
{
   // The first part of your original function is fine...

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   // But you need to return the response!
   return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that and still get nothing when I ` $json = json_decode(Input::get('json'));
     echo $json;`, but we're close !!

Comment: Put this together with my other answer and see where it gets you.

Comment: I did put them together and when I `echo $json;` in my get() function - I got nothing, blank, __________

Comment: `dd(Input::get('json'));`  keep return `null` so my post() function is **not** posting anything at all

Comment: Ok, then you probably need to debug the cURL response. Look at the response headers and the response code to see if there's some info from the server. First random guess, are you sure 'json' is the correct parameter to pass them? Maybe they are expecting JSON in the post body instead. (Just a thought).

Answer (score 0):

You can't print stuff on the server side if your client is a script (ie: not the browser).

Everything you print on the server side will be returned to the client (the post() script).

That being said, your json should be present in the `$response` variable. You can output that. But it's not the best way to debug the api requests.

The easier way would be remove the dd() and write to a log file instead.